# How do I pass a generic type to a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

Why can't I call `SomeGenericMethod<SomeGenericType<>>`?

```
class NotGeneric { }

class Generic<T> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintType(typeof(NotGeneric));
        PrintType(typeof(Generic<>));
        PrintType<NotGeneric>();
        PrintType<Generic<>>(); // compiler goes crazy here
    }

    static void PrintType<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    static void PrintType(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically `typeof` can take a generic class name that doesn't have the generic type defined, but if you pass a type as a generic it has to be a completely defined type which `Generic<>` isn't.

Comment: @juharr As usual here in SO, the best answer so far is in the comments. So it's safe to say that is **impossible** to  do so?

Comment: Well I think rbaghbanli is saying the same thing.  But no you cannot pass `Generic<>` as a generic type.  Note if you do `typeof(Generic<object>)` the `Type` you get is similar to `typeof(Generic<>)` but the `GenericTypeArguments` will not be an empty array, while `GenericTypeParameters` will be.  `typeof` just gives you an object that describes the type you passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I call `SomeGenericMethod<SomeGenericType<>>`

The simplest answer is: because the [language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) says so:

> **4.4 Constructed types**
>
> A generic type declaration, by itself, denotes an unbound generic type that is used as a “blueprint” to form many different types, by way of applying type arguments. The type arguments are written within angle brackets (< and >) immediately following the name of the generic type. A type that includes at least one type argument is called a constructed type. A constructed type can be used in most places in the language in which a type name can appear. **An unbound generic type can only be used within a typeof-expression (§7.6.11).**

> **4.4.3 Bound and unbound types**
>
> The term unbound type refers to a non-generic type or an unbound generic type. The term bound type refers to a non-generic type or a constructed type.
>   An unbound type refers to the entity declared by a type declaration. An unbound generic type is not itself a type, and cannot be used as the type of a variable, argument or return value, or as a base type. **The only construct in which an unbound generic type can be referenced is the typeof expression (§7.6.11).**

Why does the C# spec says so? Because the [CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) dictates that as well:

> **II.9.4 Instantiating generic types**
>
> ...
>
> The CLI does not support partial instantiation of generic types.  And generic types shall not appear uninstantiated anywhere in metadata signature blobs.

Ok, now let's stop with the legalese. The actual answer to your question is:

When you call `SomeMethod<SomeType>()` for the first time, the CLR will invoke the JIT compiler, which will read `SomeMethod<T>`, substitute `T`, and *create* new executable code which represents `SomeMethod<SomeType>`.

When you call `SomeMethod<SomeOtherType>()`, the process needs to be repeated, brand new code will be generated for `SomeMethod<SomeOtherType>`.

You can't just create valid code for an unbound generic type like `Generic<>`. In the general case, the JIT can't know what code representation to generate without knowing `T`.

- If `T` is a `string` and your method declares a local variable of type `T`, the JIT will allocate stack space or use a register with the size of a native pointer.
- If `T` is a `Guid`, the JIT will have to allocate stack space for a fixed 128 bits value. It can't generate code if it doesn't know what `T` is going to be.

Therefore, *in general*, you can't generate executable code for an unbound type. Why you arguably *could* do just that for the snippet you provided, this would require special-casing, and your calling code would stop working if you added a `T` local in the `PrintType` method. As generics have to be reusable across assemblies, calling code cannot assume anything about the called method.

Comment: Now that's an answer! So in the end it's because the JIT compiler doesn't know what to generate for `Generic<>`in the method call (it's JIT compilation "fault").

Answer (score 7):

Compiler needs specialized type to specialize the generic method and `Generic<>` is not specialized, it is generic. So, while `Generic<>` is a type, it is not specialized to be used for specialization of generic method.

Comment: The `Generic<>` in `typeof(Generic<>)` is solved at compiled time, doesn't it?

Comment: As I wrote, 'Generic<>' is a type, so there is no problem with 'typeof(Generic<>)'. It is generic type. But generic types cannot be used for specialization, since they are not specialized themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintType<Generic<YOU NEED TO PUT TYPE HERE>>();
```

Comment: You should look at the question as why is it OK to do `typeof(Generic<>)`.

Answer (score -2):

try something like this:

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public void PrintType(T param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of why `PrintType(typeof(Generic<>))` works by `PrintType<Generic<>>();` doesnt'?

Comment: you obviously can't use `Generic<>`, you need to specify the type, i.e. `Generic<object>`

Comment: Right but the OP is really asking why `typeof(Generic<>)` does work.